# Stop JBoss 5.0.1 from deploying everything in a WAR File

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

I have the following problem:

Originally I had a plain executable Java-Application (A class with main in a JAR and lots of dependent libraries)
Now I needed to extend this to be part of a webservice.
The problem is: When I deploy my application with it's libraries as part of a war, deployment fails because of certain artifacts in it. Chiefly among them a JAR with a JPA 2 persistence context in it. When trying to deploy this, JBoss fails for it does not understand JPA 2 but tires to deploy the persistence context.

My question is this:
Can I stop JBoss from trying to deploy everything and make ist just use the JARs it finds as dependent libraries and just start my servlet?

EDIT: For clarification: I'd like to disable JBoss recursive inspection of a WAR-File it is not (primarily) about classloader-separation I figured that one out, I think.
Basically I'd like the server to treat everything but the declared servlet as a library and not for instance a persistence context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a class loader to seperate yor war from the server libs.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration

In your jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading> 
      <loader-repository>com.example:archive=unique-archive-name</loader-repository> 
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant. JBoss has this facility for introspecting EARs and WARs looking for things inside them that it can also deploy recursively.

Comment: Thanks technoSpino but skaffman is right. I tried your way and yes I mean this recursive loading thing.